# vw on osx capped at 1440px?

Tags: html, css, macos

Today I noticed that on my windows pc with a resolution of `1920 x 1080`, websites with `100vw` render as you would expect, with body @ `width: 1920px`... However, swap over to mac with resolution of `2880 x 1800` and even though **screen zoom is set to 100%** the body is only rendering at `1440px`? I checked this across Chrome, Firefox and Safari, all of which yield the same results.

I thought that I would create a snippet to test this theory.

```css
body{ overflow:hidden }
content{
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<content></content>
```

The results for content resolution in pixels (w x h)... 
*Note that 100vh will never equal screen resolution height.*

**Windows**

Firefox: `1920 x 971`

Chrome: `1920 x 974`

IE11: `2258.82 x 1158.82` umm ok IE

**OSX**

Firefox `1440 x 794`

Chrome: `1440 x 799`

Safari: `1440 x 812`

---

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS deals with [css pixels](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/understanding-css-units/), not "physical pixels". 2x, 3x, 4x resolution displays rightly state they have 2x, 3x, and 4x resolutions, but when it comes down to it, for the sake of not breaking the entire web, browsers rendering engines have to convert the physical pixels into CSS pixels, so your 2880 resolution on a 2x display only has 1440 CSS pixels.

Comment: That is a fantastic link! And thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX with retina displays there is a display scaling setting set by default to `1440 x 900`. So even though the *true* display resolution is `2880 x 1800`, this will never be the active viewport dimensions. This issue / 'feature' is for all OSX applications, not only in browsers / web pages.

Comment: Has nothing to do with OSX - it has to do with CSS pixels vs physical pixels. There are android phones that are 4x nowadays, but in order to maintain backward compatibility, rendering engines need to convert physical pixels into a reference unit usually referred to (by web developers anyway) as a CSS pixel. In the android SDK, they are referred to as density independent pixels (dpi). So a 2x, 3x, or 4x display could all have the same number of dpis